# The main function seems to be not working in python

Tags: python

```
def main():
    print("Hello :")
    myMessage=input("Enter The Code :")
    myKey=int(input("Enter The Secret Key :"))

    cipehertext=encryptMessage(myKey,myMessage)


    # Print the encrypted string in ciphertext to the screen, with
    # a | (called "pipe" character) after it in case there are spaces at
    # the end of the encrypted message.
    print(ciphertext+'|')

    # Copy the encrypted string in ciphertext to the clipboard.
    pyperclip.copy(ciphertext)

       //  There are more codes....
     # .........................................
       # Keep looping until pointer goes past the length of the message.
        while pointer<len(message):
        # Place the character at pointer in message at the end of the
        # current column in the ciphertext list.
            ciphertext[col]+=message[pointer]

        #move pointer over

        # Convert the ciphertext list into a single string value and return it.
        return ''.join(ciphertext)

    # If transpositionEncrypt.py is run (instead of imported as a module) call
    # the main() function.
    if __name__=="__main__":
        main()
```

I have a problem with the above code. Please help me find my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your `if __name__` statement is *inside* the `main` function, so it will never be executed. Remove the indentation.